# How to set a case insensitive password to a PDF file?

Tags: c#, pdf

Using following code i can set password to PDF Files but that should be Case insensitive, How to set case insensitive password?

```
string InputFile = strFilePath;
string OutputFile = strFilePathEncrypt;

using (Stream input = new FileStream(InputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
       using (Stream output = new FileStream(OutputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
       {                
           PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(input);
           PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, output, false, strPDFPassword, "secret", PdfWriter.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS);
           reader.Close();
       }
}
```

Comment: I think case sensitivity is a designed feature of PDF security, not an option you can set.

Comment: what library is `PdfEncryptor` from?

Comment: @DanielA.White not sure it matters, its a specification. Passwords are case sensitive. I'll find the ref here in a minute.

Comment: Whoever gave you the requirement for case insensitive passwords is a complete idiot. Please, tell them that for me.  A complete goddamned idiot.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand the downvotes... the question is clear and well written, even if we don't like what he is trying to do.

Comment: http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf Page 126, by virtue of the method for encrypting the passwords, they are case sensitive. The hashes wouldn't be the same if they were different case, and it doesn't say anything about case insensitivity or taking input data and modifying it before encryption (make lower or upper case).

Comment: How about only allowing passwords without letters? That seems to be the only way (short of programming and distributing own security providers) to fulfill the requirement. And indeed, the downvotes are inappropriate.

Comment: @mkl I was thinking about only allowing upper case or lower case characters, but that could still be confusing for the final user. The idea of using only numbers is indeed the simplest one.

Comment: *using only numbers* - or special characters, symbols etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do cannot be done by using standard encryption algorithms from the PDF specification.

PDF allows encrypting the document using one of two algorithms, RC4 or AES. Both algorithms are [symetric-key algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm#Types_of_symmetric-key_algorithms), meaning that they use the same key for encrypting and decrypting the data. In order to have "case insensivity", you would need to have several possible keys that can decrypt the same data, none of these two algorithms allow such thing.

Comment: Please guide me how can i set case insensitive password for pdf files, using standard encryption algorithms is not able set case insensitive password but we can use customized code to set case insensitive password

Comment: @SharanammaJekeen If you still want to implement a custom security handler, then you will have to implement a plug-in for Acrobat Reader, which is not going to be easy. You can start here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/reader/topic_drm.html, but please read this post first, specially the last two comments: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1689003